# Splash screen while application is initializing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My application is taking about 3-5 seconds to start up. I would like to provide feedback to the user while waiting, with a splash screen. Can someone guide me on how to implement a splash screen while the application is initializing?

My application consists mainly a `tabPane` with a few numbers of `tabs`. Each tab has its own controller and FXML.

I've tried `preloader` but it doesn't work for my case or I'm not sure how to configure it to make it work. Most of the sources online used a "timer" but it just doesn't make any sense doing so.

Loading of FXMLs:

> Oct 22, 2018 1:54:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.71
>
> Oct 22, 2018 1:54:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.71
>
> Oct 22, 2018 1:54:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.71
>
> Oct 22, 2018 1:54:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.71
>
> Oct 22, 2018 1:54:56 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
>   WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.71

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You used a scenebuilder with JavaFX version of 8.0.171, but the JVM that runs the application is at 8.0.71. Some functions may be modified/added at later version of Java, so using an older JVM could potentially cause a runtime exception.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest

Comment: if the warning disturb you you can add `com.sun.javafx.util.Logging.getJavaFXLogger().setLevel(sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.Level.OFF);` in the begin of you main

Answer (score 0):

1 - create you fxml splash screen

2 - in the main, link the spashscreen like here :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    prStage = primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/SplashScreen.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    prStage.setScene(scene);
    prStage.show();
}
```

3 - in the SplashScreenControler you need to do two things :

> 1. make your action
> 2. load the screen of your application

so you need to creat a Task class inside your controller like this :

```
public class splashscreenController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Pane panParent;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        new Thread(new SplashScreen()).start();
    }

    class SplashScreen extends Task {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            //make something (here thrad.sleep)
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("your/javafx/gui.fxml"));

            //need to be done after the initialized methode
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    assert root != null;
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    //show your principal windows
                    stage.
                    MainJavaFx.setPrimaryStage(stage);

                    //close your splashScreen
                  ((Stage) panParent.getScene().getWindow()).close();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you need more information, there is a very good video of the subject [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f06uUtkmtDE)